# How to properly apply and customize a global navigation drawer with Activities

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

I am working on a big app that has recently adapted the drawer navigation style and now I'm trying to customize some of the elements. 
Because of its great size and complexity it was decided to adapt the navigation drawer to Activities and Fragment Activites instead of Fragments as the extended standard use.

For that I created a base Drawer activity called NavDrawer, which is inherited/extended by all of those activities that need to navigate with the Drawer. Every Activity that extends NavDrawer Activity calls NavDrawer onCreate method by calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.activity_layout) adding its layout_id instead of executing setContentView(R.layout_id). 
 This base Activity also handles all the intent calls to the other different activities whenever the user clicks on one of the sections/textviews.

I managed to make it work pretty well so far but I'm facing now a weird issue when customizing the Typeface of the TextViews inside the drawer. First time it is launched the app, I can see all the links without the proper style, but **only** after selecting one of the sections of the drawer, navigating to it and opening again the drawer, I see the textviews properly formated with my custom font.

I have been struggling with it for a few days already, and I am sure it has to be a stupid rookie mistake but I can´t figure it out what it is.

This is the NavDrawer class OnCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int resLayoutID) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(resLayoutID);
    AC = (ApplicationController)getApplicationContext();
    mModel = AC.getModel();
    //Setting up controls for the navigation drawer 
    if(AC.getModel().hasRatedApp() != null && AC.getModel().hasRatedApp()){
        mLinksTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_links_has_rated);
    }
    else
        mLinksTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_links_has_not_rated);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_cont);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_links);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AC, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mLinksTitles){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Typeface mFaceR = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Light.ttf"));

            return v;

        }
    });
```

I would really appreciate any help or code you could provide me since I´m still quite new in Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I just found out what was going on, actually I set by mistake another adapter for my mDrawerList later in the code. As I said, stupid rookie mistake, but the code above still worked for me and hope it can help other people to customize their Navigation Drawers too.